# Rstudio error when exporting ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to export a simple barplot using ggplot2. Everything works fine, but when the plot is printed it states the following error:

`In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  Zeichensatzfamilie in der Windows Zeichensatzdatenbank nicht gefunden`

In english it would say:

`In grid.Call(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), ... :
font family not found in Windows font database`

When I then try to export the file as pdf using the export button on top of the plot it never finishes saving the plot and I have to close Rstudio with the taskmanager.

I already read I should install the extrafont package, import and load the fonts, which I also did. This is the code I used:

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
font_import()
y
loadfonts()

Data <- Liposarcoma.ARSA_2 #txt. file with my data
newData <- Data[-c(1,2),] #delete Header


errors <- as.numeric(newData$V10)


samplev <- data.frame(samples=(newData$V3), Target=(as.numeric(newData$V8)))
samplev         #create dataframe for Target/ref


dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
limits <- aes(ymax = samplev$Target + errors,
              ymin = samplev$Target - errors)
p <- ggplot(data = samplev, aes(x = samples, y = Target))

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = dodge, fill="darkgrey") +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(samplev$samples), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold")
        ) +
        ylab("Target/Reference") +
        ggtitle("ARSA: Liposarcoma cell lines") +
        geom_text(data=samplev, aes(x=samples, y=Target+0.15, label=Target, vjust=0))
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run this without using RStudio?

Comment: we can't reproduce your error, we don't have access to your dataset. you don't seem to ask for a different font in your plot

Comment: There is a function named `pdfFonts`. It might be used to change the default fonts for that graphics device, although (not being an RStudio user yet)  I suppose that RStudio might have its own mechanism for controlling graphics devices?

Comment: Have you tried using the `pdf()` device or `ggsave()` instead of the RStudio button? Or setting a font that you know you have?

Comment: @Dason : Yes, I get the same error without using RStudio

Comment: @42 : I tried the following: Arial <- Type1Font(family = "Arial", 
                   metrics = c("C:/Users/Sara/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/extrafontdb/metrics/arial.afm.gz", 
                               "C:/Users/Sara/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/extrafontdb/metrics/arialbd.afm.gz",  
                               "C:/Users/Sara/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/extrafontdb/metrics/ariali.afm.gz", 
                               "C:/Users/Sara/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/extrafontdb/metrics/arialbi.afm.gz"))
pdfFonts(Arial = Arial)

Comment: and before plotting the graph: pdf(file = "LiposarcomaARSA.pdf", family="Arial")        ;So I set up Arial with the arial fonts I get from extrafonts and put it in pdfFonts. The error still occurs.

Comment: @alistaire : When I´m using pdf() it saves a pdf file but when I try to open it it says that it can´t because it is either used by another program or broken.

Comment: You closed the `pdf` device with `dev.off()`? Did `ggsave` do the same thing? Last-ditch, you might try outputting via `knitr` instead. It has some options about how to render .pdfs, or you can work around R's pdf capabilities altogether by knitting to HTML, and then saving as a .pdf in your browser. Not really recommended, but it'd work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. The problem was that I thought I would specify my x-labels by using:

```
axis.text.x=element_text(samplev$samples)
```

But the first element in element_text implements the fonts, not data! That is why it could not find the font, because the data in samplev$samples is not a font name. The code looks now like this and works perfectly fine:

```
pdf(file = "Liposarcoma ARSA.pdf")
p <- ggplot(data = samplev, aes(x = samples, y = Target))

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = dodge, fill="#3399FF") +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold")
        ) +
        ylab("Target/Reference") +
        ggtitle("ARSA: Liposarcoma cell lines") +
        geom_text(data=samplev, aes(x=samples, y=Target+0.1, label=Target, vjust=0))
dev.off()
```